# Java operators priority

Tags: java

I'm looking into the following part of code:

```
int a =2;
int b =3;
int c =4;
int d =4;
System.out.println(a==2 || (b==3&&c==4) && d==5);
System.out.println(d==5 && (b==3&&c==4) || a==2);
```

According to http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php I expect && perform earlier then ||, so logically it should look like that

```
if(d==5&&((b==3&&c==4)||a==2)) 
if((a==2||(b==3&&c==4))&&d==5)
```

and be false, but I'm getting true in both cases above.

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE:
Please do not suggest results of true/true:

`d==5&&((b==3&&c==4)||a==2)` returns false

`d==5&&(b==3&&c==4)||a==2` returns true

My question is that according to operators priority I believe

`d==5&&(b==3&&c==4)||a==2` should be interpreted as

`d==5&&((b==3&&c==4)||a==2)`

Comment: Consider using parantheses to group expressions that require intimate knowledge of the precedence table.

Comment: if(d==5&&((b==3&&c==4)||a==2)) should return false, not depending if a equals 2 or not.

Comment: `&&` has more priority than `||` but always prefer paranthesis to avoid pain to the readers of your code.

Comment: @dred17 why? There you have `false && (true && true) || true`, which evaluates to `false || true` and thus to `true`.

Comment: You've set `d` to 4, not `5`.  Is that your issue?

Comment: @glgl Actually, OP has `false && ((true && true) || true)`.

Comment: If you use an OR - operator (||) then it will always choose true, regardless of the priority of your operators. True OR False or vice versa will turn out True. Only False OR False will be false. Maybe you have to set brackets to define the scope of your OR statement

Comment: @E_net4 No, in the upper code not. The lower code is not executed by him (as far as I understand), but he wrongly thinks that they are equivalent (which they are not).

Comment: @glgl I see, I really wasn't expecting two different sets of equations.

Comment: @DuKes0mE Priority matters e. g. in `a && b || c`: `(a && b) || c` and `a && (b || c)` are different.

Comment: @glglgl Yeah, I edited my comment and suggested to use brackets to define the scope of that OR statement. Just because the OR statement turned out False || True doesnt mean the output will be false, because false came in first (comparing to a True || False).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [reference you give](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php), `&&` "binds tighter" than `||` (as it has a higher precedence), so `a && b || c` is interpreted as `(a && b) || c` and `a || b && c` as `a || (b && c)`. Thus, in all cases you have `a==2` making everything `true`.

Especially, your belief expressed in

> My question is that according to operators priority I believe
>
> `d==5&&(b==3&&c==4)||a==2` should be interpreted as
>
> `d==5&&((b==3&&c==4)||a==2)`

is wrong.

Comment: Isn't it conflicts priority taken from http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php?

Comment: @dred17: are you sure you know what *higher* precedence means?

Comment: @dred17 Not at all. It is exactly what this table says.

Comment: @dred17 `d==5&&(b==3&&c==4)||a==2` is interpreted as `((d==5)&&(b==3&&c==4)) || (a==2)`

Comment: @Holger now, I believe I do

Answer (score 2):

In this part:

```
if(a==2||(b==3&&c==4)&&d==5){
```

It will evaluate `a==2` and will say yes a is 2 so will print true irrespective of what's on the right hand side.

In other case:

```
if(d==5&&((b==3&&c==4)||a==2))
```

It will evaluate `d==5` which is false and then straight away will see there is an or condition (will skip && condition) and will see a is 2 and will enter if and will print true.

In short, `||` and `&&` is know as short circuit operation which evaluates all or none. Meaning if you have `condition1 || condition2` it will evaluate condition2 if and only if condition1 fails.

While if you have `condition1 && condition2`, it will evaluate condition2 if and only if condition1 is true.